# How to understand the red and green blinking lights in Trane gas furnace?

Tags: hvac, repair

My 8 year old Trane Model tuh2d120a9v5va furnace is not giving out heat, but the blower is on.  The service people are all busy due to the recent storms.  I imagine the ignition is not working.

There is a little glass viewing window.  I see red and green flashing lights. The red flashes 4 times, the green 3 times, and these overlap.  What do these lights mean?

Comment: Model tuh2d 120a9 v5va  YES. There is info on the inside of the access panel.  Four red flashes means open limit switch.  That seems like real work (and expensive).

Comment: @Yehuda_NYC, might not be "real work" or that expensive.  Some limit switches can be reset with a button, and some may need to be cleaned, etc.

Comment: That doesn't look like a model number (and doesn't return search results). Please add to and update your post instead of putting new information in comments.

Comment: As JPhi said, fixes like this are often a matter of cleaning carbon off a sensor or simply replacing it. Furnace parts aren't usually terribly expensive. The cost of repair by a professional covers trip expenses and liability for repairs and incidentals. It doesn't reflect just the actual repair cost. Finding the problem can be tricky, but that's 90% of the battle. I've saved $thousands by replacing inducer fans, blower motors, and smaller components myself with little experience.

Comment: @isherwood  Why not put your comment on looking at the inside panel for the codes.

Comment: I consider that only part of the answer. The other part is understanding what should be done next to make the repair.

Comment: @isherwood This question was about the lights. I just posted a separate question about what to do next.